# Will browsers automatically preload URLs in JavaScript variables?

Tags: jquery

I'm making a site in which I'm using jQuery to change background images on a page. There will be quite a few images substituted through the course of the site.

By declaring variables like this at the beginning of the script, will it preload the images and therefore allow for faster substitution of images?  Or, if I do it with too many images (like 50), will it slow things down? or do the variables use too much memory?

Are there any issues you see with this plan, or is there a better way?

```
var img1 = "url('images/wackawacka.jpg') repeat";

var img2 = "url('images/wabbaawacka.jpg') repeat";

var img3  etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just declaring those variables as strings, JavaScript won't preload those images.

Take a look at this article for how to preload images with JavaScript: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317

Using that method when the document is loaded, you can load all the images into the users' cache after the page loads, so when they switch, they'll be quickly accessible.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at that article. If I used variables in the way that I do in the OP, will it degrade performance by having multiple variables set at the same time? i.e. does it keep multiple channels open to the server? or is that not an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of CSS sprites? That will significantly speed up image loading and will also improve performance.

Comment: You can't use CSS sprites if you want repeating background images.

Comment: Yes. But downloading one giant file is better than opening multiple connections to download smaller files.

Comment: @Mrchief that's not always true. If the other images aren't going to be viewed right away, there's no sense in waiting for all of them to load before displaying the page to the user. If you only load the initial background image, the page will load faster. Then after the page loads, you can download the other background images.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, its not meant to be a silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is not bad, although you do have to use "new Image", but depending on your use case, you might be better off using image sprites.

http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Here is an example image sprite at Google:

http://www.google.com/images/experiments/nav_logo77.png

The idea is to load one image file with multiple icons combined, and then change where the top and left of the image point to.

Update:

Here's a preloadImage function

```
function preloadImage(src) {
  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = src;
}
```

Comment: Can this work (and is it practcial) with large images? Each image is supposed to  fill the whole browser window?

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend using new Image for each of the images... function preloadImage(src) {
  var myImage = new Image(); 
  myImage.src = src;
}